# Are there any reasons to not store non-serializable data in Redux, if I don't need serialization myself?

Tags: redux

According to Redux Toolkit's [documentation](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions), and many answers here on Stack Overflow, storing non-serializable values in Redux is not recommended, and that's why they print warnings in the console when that happens.

However, the only issues they raised were that it could bug Redux's dev tools and that it wouldn't be possible to serialize data when needed.

If I don't need these features, is there any other reason, specially when it comes to performance, to not disable these warnings?

Being able to store classes in Redux would make it easier to type check objects, including nested ones, without using "value is X" workarounds in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs (that I wrote! :)  ) tell you: the code will *run*, technically.

But it absolutely does lead to potential mutation issues, as well as wasting the ability to see that data in the DevTools, and the DevTools are one of the primary reasons to use Redux in the first place.

So, as all the answers say: **we strongly encourage that you *do not* put classes in the Redux state**.  That's not how Redux is meant to be used.

If you *absolutely* want to, I guess you can.  But it's not the right approach, and it really is likely to cause issues down the road.

(I *am* curious what you mean by "easier to type check objects"...)

Comment: By mutation issues, do you mean the state will be re-updated when its not supposed to? As in, we will get more re-renders when using useSelector? That part confuses me. As for why instances of classes are easier to type-check, I meant that using instanceof is the easiest way to check what type an object is.

Comment: I never really used Redux's DevTools, and I mostly use Redux as a global state that can be accessed outside React. I wouldn't mind not using the DevTools, tbqh.

Comment: You are likely to get _fewer_ re-renders if you accidentally mutate. Redux and React-Redux expect that _all_ state updates will be done immutably, and rely on `===` comparisons to determine if some piece of state changed.  If you mutate state for real, then those checks don't work right.  And, as I said: the Redux DevTools are one of the biggest reasons to use Redux :) You really should try them out.